# Como acesso o ponteiro de uma struct dentro do ponteiro de uma outra struct?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

```
typedef struct vertice
{  
    int num_vertice;    
    int profundidade;    
    struct vertice **vertices_adja;

} Vertice;

typedef struct grafo
{    
   int qtd_vertices;   
   int *Vertice;

} Grafo;
```

Desejo acessar os atributos da struct 'Vertice' dentro da grafo, a maneira como estou tentando fazer é esta.

```
Grafo* criarGrafo(int *vertices, int qtd_vertices)
{     
   Grafo *grafo_A;

   grafo_A = malloc(sizeof(Grafo));

   grafo_A->Vertice = alocarVertices(qtd_vertices);

    if(grafo_A->Vertice != NULL)
    {
       grafo_A->qtd_vertices = qtd_vertices;

       int i = 0 ;

       for( ; i < qtd_vertices; i++)
       {
         (grafo_A)->Vertice[i]->num_vertice = vertices[i];  <-- Aqui está erro "error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)"
       }
        return grafo_A;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nete local onde você aponta como erro tem um pequeno falha de conceito

```
(grafo_A)->Vertice[i]->num_vertice = vertices[i];
```

(grafo_A) é um ponteiro logo -> está correto...
Você acessa Vertice porem você utilizou indexação, ou seja, Vertice[i] é uma instancia não um ponteiro logo deveria ter se utilizado um . como abaixo

```
(grafo_A)->Vertice[i].num_vertice = vertices[i];
```

Isso se da porque todo vetor/matriz é um ponteiro...

```
int a[10];
cout<<*(a)<<endl; // 'a' aponta para o primeiro endereço a[0] de memoria

// a+9 é o ultimo endereço do vetor e *(a+9) é a instancia do endereço
// então, *(a+9) == a[9]
cout << a[9] << "==" << *(a+9);
```

Ou seja, outra possivel solução seria escrever da seguinte maneira:

```
(grafo_A)->(Vertice + i)->num_vertice = vertices[i];
```

Comment: Ok, entedi, obrigado pela ajuda! Me ajudou bastante...

Comment: Por nada, marque como util se respondeu sua pergunta

Answer (score 1):

`Vertice` dentro da `struct grafo` tem tipo `int *`.
Estes dois tipos não são compatíveis.
Quando indexas um valor de tipo `int *` obtens um `int` e um valor de tipo `int` não tem membros.

Define a `struct grafo` como contendo um ponteiro para a `struct vertice`

```
typedef struct vertice
{
    int num_vertice;
    int profundidade;
    struct vertice **vertices_adja;
};

typedef struct grafo
{
   int qtd_vertices;
   struct vertice *Vertice;
};
```

Depiois disto podes fazer

```
    grafo_A->Vertice[i].num_vertice = vertices[i];
```

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, a struct ' Vertice' dentro da grafo se trata de um ponteiro, logo eu não teria que referência-lo com o operador "->", ficando assim:     grafo_A->Vertice[i]->num_vertice;        por que isso não está correto?

Comment: `Vertice` é um ponteiro de tipo `struct vertice *`; `Vertice[i]` é um objecto de tipo `struct vertice`.